# Mini split plug into existing 220 outlet?

Tags: wiring, 240v

I’d like to use my dryer 220 outlet to power a mini split. Can the 220 from the mini split be plugged into that outlet?

Comment: what mini split, show us

Comment: Are you still wanting to use it for a dryer?

Comment: How many amps does the mini split use(see label)?  How many amps does the dryer use?  If both the same, it is possible, but maybe not in code.  If one is more than the other, not a good idea.

Comment: If the dryer plug is a NEMA 10-30, that's a hard no. Probably violates the installation instructions of the mini-split, which also makes it a hard no.

Comment: CAN you?  Yes.  Should you?  Probably not.   Depending on where you are on the planet, you should need a disconnect close to the compressor unit. You probably don't have that. As others have said, the amperage may not be the same and the wire gauge not compatible.  Now if you intend to use the dryer outlet box as a connector to allow the wiring to get outside and everything matches to code, and you do not intend to use the dryer again, and you have the necessary disconnect and 120V outlet then you may be ok.  But we don't know those answers because you didn't tell us.